# How to calculate the total elapsed time through input text file using C#?

Tags: c#

I want to calculate total "Elapsed time" in "WX GSA Search".Following is my log file :

> WX Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com User:vibsharm appGUID:
>   wx Elapsed Time:875ms SaveSearchID:361 WX GSA Search =
>   Server:nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com User:gulanand appGUID: wx Elapsed
>   Time:890ms SaveSearchID:361 WX GSA Search =
>   Server:nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed
>   Time:887ms SaveSearchID:361 WX GSA Search =
>   Server:nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com User: gulanand appGUID: wx Elapsed
>   Time:875.5ms SaveSearchID:361 WX GSA Search =
>   Server:nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed
>   Time:877.6ms SaveSearchID:361

Code I wrote but is not working. Plz check Regex if it's ok or not :

```
string searchKeyword = "WX GSA Search";
string fileName = @"C:\Users\karan\Desktop\Sample log file.txt";
string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

List<string> results = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in textLines)
{
    if (line.Contains(searchKeyword))
    {
        results.Add(line);
    }
}

string x = string.Join(",",results);

List<string> users = new List<string>();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"Elapsed Time:\s*(?<timevalue>.*?)+ms");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(x);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var user = match.Groups["value"].Value;
    if (!users.Contains(time)) users.Add(time);
}

string[] s = users.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem is the regex, try this one.

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"Elapsed Time:(?<timevalue>\d+(?:\.\d)?)ms");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your regex is not exactly invalid, but it could be improved.

E.g.:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"Elapsed Time:\s*(?<value>\d+\.?\d*)\s*ms");
```

The "+" before the "ms" means that the any number of chars should be repeated one or more times - it then tries any combination possible to make the best fit and that takes time.

I changed the *.? to \d+.?\d* to only accept numeric value with optional decimals.

I also changed the (?< timevalue>... to (?< value>... so it matched your code sample.

Good luck with your quest.

Comment: Looks like you had the same idea like me. ;)

Comment: @DorgySharma The regex from Casperah (and mine also) definitively works with the string you gave us in your question. Either your string at runtime is different, or you should try to rework your methods to grab the regex matches. Have you tried to set up a breakpoint and have a look on the regex results?

Comment: i think there is some problem with the foreach loop of regex.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you extract the value in a variable named "user" and stores the value from a variable named "time".

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.Split` and a bit of `Linq` to parse the Elapsed time;

```
   TimeSpan elapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(File.ReadAllLines("c:\\log.txt")
        .Where(line => line.Contains("Elapsed Time:"))
        .Select(line => line.Split(new string[] { "Elapsed Time:"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last().Split(' ').First())
        .Select<string,double>(time => time.EndsWith("ms") ? double.Parse(time.Replace("ms","").Trim()) 
                                     : time.EndsWith("s") ? double.Parse(time.Replace("s","").Trim()) * 1000.0 : 0.0 ).Sum());
```

Comment: I tried this : var elapsedTime = results.SelectMany(line => line.ToLower().Split(' '))
                     .Where(line => line.StartsWith("time"))
                     .Select(timeLine => decimal.Parse(timeLine.Split(':')[1].Replace("ms",String.Empty)))
                     .Sum( time => time);

Comment: But the problem is i have a discrepancy in my logs : in some format it is like "Elapsed Time:975ms" and in some cases, format is like "Elapsed Time: 975ms" . How will i cover both these scenarios ?

Comment: Just add a `Trim()` to `time.Replace("ms","")` this will remove the wite space around the number, so it will be `time.Replace("ms","").Trim()`, I have updated my answer.