# I want to sum the total Elapsed time through input text file?

Tags: c#

I want to sum the total "Elapsed time" for "GSA Search" only, using C sharp :

Following is my log file :

```
WX Search = Server:testserver User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:975ms SaveSearchID:361
WX Search = Server:testserver User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:875ms SaveSearchID:361
GSA Search = Server:testserver User:gulanand appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:890ms SaveSearchID:361
GSA Search = Server:testserver User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:887ms SaveSearchID:361
GSA Search = Server:testserver User: gulanand appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:875.5ms SaveSearchID:361
GSA Search = Server:testserver User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:877.6ms SaveSearchID:361
```

Code i have tried is :

```
string searchKeyword = "WX GSA Search";
            string fileName = @"C:\Users\karan\Desktop\Sample log file.txt";
            string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

            List<string> results = new List<string>();

            foreach (string line in textLines)
            {
                if (line.Contains(searchKeyword))
                {
                    results.Add(line);
                }
            }

            string x = string.Join(",", results);
            List<string> time = new List<string>();
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"Elapsed Time:(?<timevalue>\d+(?:\.\d)?)ms");
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(x);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                var value = match.Groups["timevalue"].Value;
                if (!time.Contains(value)) time.Add(value);
            }
```

Comment: are you looking to parse the log file??? What have you tried? Show some code

Comment: I see that you have corrected your code a little since http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183740/how-to-calculate-the-total-elapsed-time-through-input-text-file-using-c/15183793#15183793.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you started

```
string text = @"WX Search = Server:testserver User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:975ms SaveSearchID:361 WX Search = Server:testserver User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:875ms SaveSearchID:361 GSA Search = Server:testserver User:gulanand appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:890ms SaveSearchID:361 GSA Search = Server:testserver User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:887ms SaveSearchID:361 GSA Search = Server:testserver User: gulanand appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:875.5ms SaveSearchID:361 GSA Search = Server:testserver User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:877.6ms SaveSearchID:361";
var elapsedTime = text.ToLower().Split(' ').Where(line => line.StartsWith("time"))
                  .Select(timeLine => decimal.Parse(timeLine.Split(':')[1].Replace("ms",String.Empty)))
                  .Sum( time => time);
```

Output in ms: 5380.1

Ahh, I just noticed you said "GSA Search" only. In that case you first need to filter for "GSA Search" then apply the above code. In your code you already do that with

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\karan\Desktop\Sample log file.txt";
            string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

            List<string> results = new List<string>();

            foreach (string line in textLines)
            {
                if (line.Contains(searchKeyword))
                {
                    results.Add(line);
                }
            }



   var elapsedTime = results.SelectMany(line => line.ToLower().Split(' '))
                     .Where(line => line.StartsWith("time"))
                     .Select(timeLine => decimal.Parse(timeLine.Split(':')[1].Replace("ms",String.Empty)))
                     .Sum( time => time);
```

Comment: i need to calculate only for GSA Search not for entire search and after that their average. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DorgySharma you already do that in your code by filtering beforehand.

Comment: yes it worked. Many thanks. One more thing now if i want it's average how do i approach ? Can i put this entire sum in List or array and then calculate their average.

Comment: yes, of course, the same way I use the Sum method you can use the Average method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb909251(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: One more thing, i have a discrepancy in my logs : in some format it it like "Elapsed Time:975ms" and in some cases, format is like "Elapsed Time: 975ms" . How will i cover both these scenarios ? Once again lot of thanks.

Comment: you can add a trim to this line `timeLine.Split(':')[1].Trim().Replace("ms",String.Empty)`