# I am having difficulty in parsing logs for a particular field with values having spaces?

Tags: c#

I want to calculate total "Elapsed Time" in "GSA Search", but i am facing discrepancy.
 In some cases format is "Elapsed Time: 97ms" and in some cases it is "Elapsed Time:97ms". How can i cover both scenarios ?

Following is my logs file format:

```
WX Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.com User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time: 975ms SaveSearchID:361
WX Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.com User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time: 875ms SaveSearchID:361
GSA Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.com User:gulanand appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:890ms SaveSearchID:361
GSA Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.com User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:887ms SaveSearchID:361
GSA Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.com User: gulanand appGUID: wx Elapsed Time: 875.5ms SaveSearchID:361
GSA Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.com User:vibsharm appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:877.6ms SaveSearchID:361
```

My code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string searchKeyword = "WX GSA Search";
            string fileName = @"C:\Users\karan\Desktop\Sample log file.txt";
            string[] textLines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

            List<string> results = new List<string>();

            foreach (string line in textLines)
            {
                if (line.Contains(searchKeyword))
                {
                    results.Add(line);
                }
            }
            var elapsedTime = results.SelectMany(line => line.ToLower().Split(' '))
            .Where(line => line.StartsWith("time"))
            .Select(timeLine => decimal.Parse(timeLine.Split(':')[1].Replace("ms", String.Empty)))
            .Average(time => time);
            Console.WriteLine(elapsedTime);
            // keep screen from going away
            // when run from VS.NET
            Console.ReadLine();
            }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the total elapsed time through input text file using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183740/how-to-calculate-the-total-elapsed-time-through-input-text-file-using-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        string x = @"Elapsed Time: 97ms";
        int startIndex = x.LastIndexOf("Elapsed Time");
        int endIndex = x.LastIndexOf("ms");
        //Here there might be a problem, you might need to change to endIndex - startIndex +1
        string valueSubString = x.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
        decimal value = decimal.Parse(valueSubString.Replace(':').Trim());
```

Comment: var elapsedTime = results.SelectMany(line => line.ToLower().Split(' '))
            .Where(line => line.StartsWith("time"))
            .Select(timeLine => decimal.Parse(timeLine.Split(':')[1].Replace("ms", String.Empty)))Trim()
            .Average(time => time);

Comment: It is experiencing problems in this line : decimal.Parse(timeLine.Split(':')[1].Replace("ms", String.Empty).Trim()))

Comment: Did you cover both the scenarios i mean "Elapsed Time: "with space and without space ("Elapsed Time:")

Comment: @DorgySharma Still not giving me info. What problems on that line? Yes, if you call that chain of methods on a string even if it has or doesn't have spaces, it will work.

Comment: @DorgySharma if it worked before, only with the lines where there was no space between the value and the `ms` it will work in my version with the space also.

Comment: In Decimal.Parse, calling .Trim function is unnecessary.

Comment: Need to Cover scenarios where "Elapsed Time:<space>value" and "Elapsed Time:value"

Comment: @DorgySharma sorry, i realised now. Well, do it old style, find the last index of the string "Elapsed Time" and the last index of "ms" and then you know that the string between those indexes is in the form `: xxx` or without space, so you just need to remove the `:` and the spaces and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed things up if you reduce string allocations, like so:

(Ideally I'd use a finite-state machine parser entirely, but reading line-by-line is also acceptable):

```
Decimal totalMs = 0;
Int32 totalRecords = 0;

using(StringReader rdr = new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.UTF8)) {

    String line;
    while( (line = rdr.ReadLine()) != null ) {

        if( line.IndexOf("GSA Search", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) != 0 ) continue;

        Int32 idxStart = line.IndexOf("Elapsed time:", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) + "Elapsed time:".Length;
        Int32 idxEnd   = line.IndexOf("ms", idxStart, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase );

        Decimal lineMs = Decimal.Parse( line.Substring( idxStart, idxEnd - idxStart ) );
        totalMs += lineMs;
        totalRecords++;
    }
}
Decimal average = totalMs / totalRecords;
```

Calling `.Trim` is unnecessary because `Decimal.Parse` allows whitespace, although you might want to consider using `Decimal.TryParse` instead if you want to it to be more robust.